# Getting memory dump of .Net app from frozen computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windbg

From time to time my 32bit .Net program hangs the entire windows 10 OS.  I am unable to get to task manager or a console on the computer to do a dump of my .Net for analysis in windbg.  We have tried RDP, RDP to console, remote command line - but no luck accessing the computer - we just have to reboot.

Is there a way to get a Windows 10 diagnostic dump when the OS hangs, and then analyze this as a .Net app in WinDBG?  Note: my app is 32bit and dumps created for 64bit apps dont work for my app in WinDbg.

thanks

Comment: Consider using [procdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procdump), it can be configured to take dumps on a wide variety of conditions, including periodically if nothing more specific can be pinned down. If a single user process manages to make the entire machine unresponsive this is typically caused by it allocating so much memory that thrashing happens and/or 100% CPU, so memory/CPU conditions should be enough. You can also limit process memory by using jobs, but there seem to be no good command-line tools for this.

Comment: "hangs the entire windows 10 OS" indicates that you might configure the machine to capture a kernel dump.

Comment: You can configure the keyboard to cause a blue screen to debug a kernel dump by pressing some hotkey. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you your windows machine is frozen and is not responding to any input device (keyboard/mouse), the only way to get a dump from that machine is to set up windows kernel debugging.

You will have to follow the steps [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-kernel-mode-debugging-in-windbg--cdb--or-ntsd). Once your machine is setup for kernel debugging, and you have verified that you can break into the kernel of the machine where your program is running, wait until the machine is unresponsive and then break into the machine.

This will allow you to examine what windows is currently doing. There is a little bit of learning curve to set up the debugger and use windbg kernel debugging but this is the most powerful debugging environment that windows offer. You can download [windbg here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools). It comes with comprehensive documentation.